# Add autocompletion in dash

Tags: autocomplete, dash

Is it possible to get at least "some" autocompletion in a `dash` shell like in `bash`?

At least for the existing filenames in a path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, dash doesn't have completion. Otherwise it would be called bash. Dash was designed to execute shell scripts fast and with a minimum of memory, it wasn't intended to be used interactively.

The best way to get completion in dash is to run `exec zsh` or `exec fish`. Or, if you want to stick with a shell that doesn't use much memory, use a BusyBox sh build that includes completion.

If you want to stick with dash, you can do what people did before completion existed: use wildcards. For example, instead of typing a prefix of a file name and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type a prefix of a file name and then type `*`. The prefix needs to be unique, otherwise multiple file names will be interpolated.

To list “completions”, call `ls` or run `echo` on the wildcard pattern.

If you use the same file name (or other string) multiple times, store it in a variable.

Comment: `exec fish` just closed it here (using yakuake with dash as default)

Comment: @AquariusPower Because you did not have the `fish` shell installed.  Both of those commands simply starts another shell in place of the current `dash` shell (I assume the commands were meant as a kind of a joke).

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting an alternative (@...)

why `dash`? for me is the resident memory usage. (I use yakuake and each bash tab is 34MB here. dash is 708KB.) The problem is I am often typing bash to have autocompletion.

The alternative: `yash` RSS=1080KB, has excellent auto-completion (may be even friendlier than bash's one). I set it as default on yakuake and no matter how many tabs I open it is very easy on memory.

I found that having yakuake start yash with `.yashrc` starting bash uses +-9MB RSS instead of 34MB! then if I want to keep something like htop, i just exit bash and get the yash low memory again to run it!

complementing https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158523/30352:
`exec zsh` used 5.5MB RSS (...@) as you may not want to stick with dash :)

Obs.: RSS thru `htop`